# codeigniter mysql transactions

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I'm new to database transactions and what i've found is extremely confusing. I have a queue table that contains email address, send datetime, and sent datetime. My cron job is constantly firing and selecting rows with the 'send datetime' passed now. It sends an email to the address and updates the 'sent datetime' column.

If this cron job fired at the exact same time, there is potential for the them to grab the same rows, thus sending the email twice.

From what i understand, transactions all depend on the success or failure or queries. How do i check that in this scenario?

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM Queue_table where send >= now LIMIT 100');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   //code to send email to $row->email;
   $this->db->query('UPDATE Queue_table SET sent = now WHERE id = '$row->id'');
}

//the following doesn't make much sense to me. What would cause
// this to be false in this scenario?

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Am i going about doing this completely wrong?

Comment: If you're using CodeIgnighter, use the SQL escaping mechanism provided: `$this->db->query('UPDATE Queue_table SET sent = now WHERE id = ?', array($row->id));` It's reckless to skip this step.

Comment: transactions are very good for rolling back queries when an error occurs. basically the $this->db->trans_status() function will detect whether or not there have been any errors in the queries that have been executed, if trans_status() === FALSE then errors occured and the previous queries should be rolled back else they are commited to the database